# How to make API accessible through same domain as Angular web app

Tags: node.js, angular, rest, api, haproxy

I have following setup:

- Angular web app with static files hosted on AWS S3 bucket
- 2 x backend NodeJS, hosted on my own servers
- 1 x HAProxy, hosted on my own server

The Angular app makes REST API calls to the public IP of HAProxy, which then load balances between the two backend servers. So far so good.

Let's say the Angular app is acessible on port 80 through http://[URL]

I would like to expose that same REST API directly to users through http://[URL]/api
So whenever /api/… is used, this would get forwarded to the HAProxy IP, so that it can get processed by the backend servers.

Looking for ways + best practice to accomplish this, as it seems like a pretty common scenario.

Thanks!